# Kubectl : Add healthcheck using TCP targetting https, do not terminate SSL on ELB for AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, kubernetes

I am working on a Kubernetes application in which we are running a nginx server. There are 2 issues we are facing currently,

one is related to healthchecks. I would like to add healthchecks which check for the container on port-443, but with TCP, Kubernetes is somehow doing that on **SSL**, causing the containers to show out of service by AWS.

Secondly, SSL Traffic is getting terminated on ELB, while still talking with container on port-443. I have added a self-signed certificate on the container inside nginx already. We redirect from http to https internally, so anything on port-80 is of no use to us. What am I doing wrong?

service.yaml :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: service-name
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: service-name-instance
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.0.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/component: backend
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: kubectl
  annotations:
      # Note that the backend talks over HTTP.
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: https
       # TODO: Fill in with the ARN of your certificate.
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: OUR ARN
       # Only run SSL on the port named "https" below.
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "TCP"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-redirect-http-to-https: "true"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-tls-ports: "443"
  name: service-name

spec:
  selector:
    app: service-name
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  - name: https
    port: 443
    targetPort: 443
```

Comment: Have you tried following this example: [TCP Liveness Probe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-a-tcp-liveness-probe)?